# Aggregates with DB2 results based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I'm trying to figure out the best way to aggregate DB2 results and group based on several factors.

Currently I have this query:

```
SELECT
    T1.VEHICLE,
    T2.VEHICLE_ID,
    T3.WORK_ORDER_ID,
    T3.JOB_CREATION,
    T5.JOB_STATUS,
    T4.JOB_STATUS_TIME
FROM SCHEMA.VEHICLE T1
INNER JOIN SCHEMA.VEHICLE_TO_WORK_ORDER T2
ON T1.VEHICLE_ID = T2.VEHICLE_ID
INNER JOIN SCHEMA.WORK_ORDER T3
ON T2.WORK_ORDER_ID = T3.WORK_ORDER_ID
INNER JOIN SCHEMA.WORK_ORDER_TO_JOB_STATUS T4
ON T3.WORK_ORDER_ID = T4.WORK_ORDER_ID
INNER JOIN SCHEMA.JOB_STATUS T5
ON T4.JOB_STATUS_ID = T5.JOB_STATUS_ID;
```

It returns these results, which are correct from a data standpoint:

```
VEHICLE    VEHICLE_ID   WORK_ORDER_ID           JOB_CREATION           JOB_STATUS          JOB_STATUS_TIME          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VEHICLE 6     6             12345       2019-09-25 00:00:09.426178      CREATED         2019-09-25 00:00:09.469059
VEHICLE 6     6             12345       2019-09-25 00:00:09.426178      ACTIVE          2019-09-25 13:40:00.981891
VEHICLE 6     6             12345       2019-09-25 00:00:09.426178      COMPLETED       2019-09-25 13:45:02.748800
VEHICLE 7     7             54321       2019-09-26 00:00:09.426178      CREATED         2019-09-26 00:00:09.469059
VEHICLE 7     7             54321       2019-09-26 00:00:09.426178      ACTIVE          2019-09-26 13:40:00.981891
VEHICLE 7     7             54321       2019-09-26 00:00:09.426178      PAUSED          2019-09-26 14:40:02.748800
VEHICLE 7     7             54321       2019-09-26 00:00:09.426178      ACTIVE          2019-09-26 14:45:09.469059
VEHICLE 7     7             54321       2019-09-26 00:00:09.426178      COMPLETED       2019-09-26 14:50:00.981891
VEHICLE 3     3             12346       2019-09-27 00:00:09.426178      OPEN            2019-09-27 13:40:02.748800
VEHICLE 3     3             12346       2019-09-27 00:00:09.426178      ACTIVE          2019-09-27 13:45:09.469059
VEHICLE 3     3             12346       2019-09-27 00:00:09.426178      PAUSED          2019-09-27 13:50:00.981891
VEHICLE 3     3             12346       2019-09-27 00:00:09.426178      CANCELLED       2019-09-27 13:51:02.748800
```

What I'm trying to do here is group by vehicle and get work orders on that vehicle in a given date range then sum up the activity times, or times between activities so that I can achieve aggregation for sum columns (this example has 3 vehicles with only one work order each, but I want to be able to look at any work orders in a date range and get the same aggregates.)

I want to get a count of each work order that was created, as well as each order  that ended in completed or cancelled for their own column, but I want a total active time which is job_status_time (time from each active to paused or active to completed, since a task could be active then paused, then active again followed by completed)

I'm hoping for results similar to this, but I just don't quite know how to aggregate this correctly:

```
VEHICLE    Created    Completed    Cancelled    Total Active Time (minutes)
------------------------------------------------------------------
6           1           1           0               5
7           1           1           0               65
3           1           0           1               5
```

How can I group these results by vehicle and still get these sum columns and aggregate time based on job_status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Db2 for LUW

```
WITH 
  RES (VEHICLE_ID, JOB_STATUS, JOB_STATUS_TIME) AS 
(
VALUES
  (6, 'CREATED',   TIMESTAMP('2019-09-25-00.00.09.469059'))
, (6, 'ACTIVE',    TIMESTAMP('2019-09-25-13.40.00.981891'))
, (6, 'COMPLETED', TIMESTAMP('2019-09-25-13.45.02.748800'))

, (7, 'CREATED',   TIMESTAMP('2019-09-26-00.00.09.469059'))
, (7, 'ACTIVE',    TIMESTAMP('2019-09-26-13.40.00.981891'))
, (7, 'PAUSED',    TIMESTAMP('2019-09-26-14.40.02.748800'))
, (7, 'ACTIVE',    TIMESTAMP('2019-09-26-14.45.09.469059'))
, (7, 'COMPLETED', TIMESTAMP('2019-09-26-14.50.00.981891'))

, (3, 'OPEN',      TIMESTAMP('2019-09-27-13.40.02.748800'))
, (3, 'ACTIVE',    TIMESTAMP('2019-09-27-13.45.09.469059'))
, (3, 'PAUSED',    TIMESTAMP('2019-09-27-13.50.00.981891'))
, (3, 'CANCELLED', TIMESTAMP('2019-09-27-13.51.02.748800'))
)
, A AS 
(
SELECT 
  VEHICLE_ID, JOB_STATUS
, JOB_STATUS_TIME
, LEAD (JOB_STATUS_TIME) OVER (PARTITION BY VEHICLE_ID ORDER BY JOB_STATUS_TIME) AS JOB_STATUS_TIME_NEXT
FROM RES
)
SELECT
  VEHICLE_ID
, COUNT(CASE JOB_STATUS WHEN 'CREATED'   THEN 1 END) AS CREATED
, COUNT(CASE JOB_STATUS WHEN 'COMPLETED' THEN 1 END) AS COMPLETED
, COUNT(CASE JOB_STATUS WHEN 'CANCELLED' THEN 1 END) AS CANCELLED
, SUM 
  (
  CASE JOB_STATUS WHEN 'ACTIVE' THEN 
    (DAYS(JOB_STATUS_TIME_NEXT) - DAYS(JOB_STATUS_TIME)) * 86400 
  + MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(JOB_STATUS_TIME_NEXT) - MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(JOB_STATUS_TIME) 
  END
  ) / 60 AS ACTIVE_MINUTES
FROM A
GROUP BY VEHICLE_ID;
```

## DB2 for iSeries & LUW

Seems that DB2 for iSeries (at least my 7.3) has a bug - an attempt to use the `DAYS(JOB_STATUS_TIME_NEXT)` expression in the query above results in SQLCODE = -171. I have no idea what's the reason: if it's because of the function argument got from the OLAP function or because of some another reason...

But, we may rewrite the query as below:

```
WITH 
  RES (VEHICLE_ID, JOB_STATUS, JOB_STATUS_TIME) AS 
(
VALUES
  (6, 'CREATED',   TIMESTAMP('2019-09-25-00.00.09.469059'))
, (6, 'ACTIVE',    TIMESTAMP('2019-09-25-13.40.00.981891'))
, (6, 'COMPLETED', TIMESTAMP('2019-09-25-13.45.02.748800'))

, (7, 'CREATED',   TIMESTAMP('2019-09-26-00.00.09.469059'))
, (7, 'ACTIVE',    TIMESTAMP('2019-09-26-13.40.00.981891'))
, (7, 'PAUSED',    TIMESTAMP('2019-09-26-14.40.02.748800'))
, (7, 'ACTIVE',    TIMESTAMP('2019-09-26-14.45.09.469059'))
, (7, 'COMPLETED', TIMESTAMP('2019-09-26-14.50.00.981891'))

, (3, 'OPEN',      TIMESTAMP('2019-09-27-13.40.02.748800'))
, (3, 'ACTIVE',    TIMESTAMP('2019-09-27-13.45.09.469059'))
, (3, 'PAUSED',    TIMESTAMP('2019-09-27-13.50.00.981891'))
, (3, 'CANCELLED', TIMESTAMP('2019-09-27-13.51.02.748800'))
)
, A AS 
(
SELECT 
  VEHICLE_ID, JOB_STATUS
, JOB_STATUS_TIME
, ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VEHICLE_ID ORDER BY JOB_STATUS_TIME) AS RN
FROM RES
)
SELECT
  A1.VEHICLE_ID
, COUNT(CASE A1.JOB_STATUS WHEN 'CREATED'   THEN 1 END) AS CREATED
, COUNT(CASE A1.JOB_STATUS WHEN 'COMPLETED' THEN 1 END) AS COMPLETED
, COUNT(CASE A1.JOB_STATUS WHEN 'CANCELLED' THEN 1 END) AS CANCELLED
, SUM 
  (
  CASE A1.JOB_STATUS WHEN 'ACTIVE' THEN 
    (DAYS(A2.JOB_STATUS_TIME) - DAYS(A1.JOB_STATUS_TIME)) * 86400 
  + MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(A2.JOB_STATUS_TIME) - MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(A1.JOB_STATUS_TIME) 
  END
  ) / 60 AS ACTIVE_MINUTES
FROM A A1
LEFT JOIN A A2 ON A2.VEHICLE_ID = A1.VEHICLE_ID AND A2.RN = A1.RN + 1
GROUP BY A1.VEHICLE_ID;
```

The result is:

```
|VEHICLE_ID |CREATED    |COMPLETED  |CANCELLED  |ACTIVE_MINUTES|
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|--------------|
|3          |0          |0          |1          |4             |
|6          |1          |1          |0          |5             |
|7          |1          |1          |0          |64            |
```

Comment: Pardon this potentially stupid question: If I'm running this directly in my database without the example data then I can just start at the first select correct?

Comment: Insert your `SELECT` statement (returning VEHICLE_ID, JOB_STATUS, JOB_STATUS_TIME columns only) instead of the `VALUES (...), ..., (...)` block.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. For some reason with mine and your example, they both give me a token error ```Token ( was not valid. Valid tokens: , FROM INTO```

Comment: I'm not positive but I think it happens at the first ```...JOB_STATUS_TIME) AS (```

Comment: Actually it seems to potentially be at the second option ```, A AS (SELECT...```

Comment: My query works well as is on Db2 for LUW. What’s your Db2 version and platform?

Comment: IBM iSeries version 7 currently

Comment: You should add the corresponding tag - `[db2-400]` in this case to your post. I've updated the answer. Please, check it.

Comment: Ah sorry about the tag mishap, noted for the future. And that did work, thank you!

Comment: Can I compound multiple conditions in a ```CASE``` so that I can look at where the status is ```CREATED ``` and that's the most recent status? IN other words, it's not been made active, cancelled OR completed?

Comment: If `COUNT(CASE JOB_STATUS WHEN 'CREATED'   THEN 1 END) ` = `COUNT(1)` then `CREATED` is the only record for the given group. If you have some other preceding records to `CREATED` then ask another question with sample data and the result needed.